# How to set headers to send mail in php when message contains attachments and HTML body

Tags: php

I need to send one mail using php code. The mail contails HTML Part, Text , and two attachments (xls) file. How do i set headers and message body . For me Only one is working at a time either mail body or attachment. Please help

Comment: Better for you if you use [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). Less time consuming, better approach, simple integration.

Comment: What have you already tried - where are you stuck?

Comment: I used PHPMailer. It worked fine.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function, i found [here](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script) , you can get some other code also if you google

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

And the Usage

```
$my_file = "somefile.zip";
$my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_path_here/";
$my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
$my_mail = "my@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
```

Function Call:

```
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```